# C# MVC form does not send data back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know it must be something stupid, but I cant seem to figure this out.  I have the following in a view:

```
 @using (@Html.BeginForm("ReceiveForm1", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="organizationID">Organization ID</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="organizationID" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Organization ID">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="externalPersonalID">External Personal ID</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" asp-for="externalPersonalID" placeholder="Enter External Personal ID">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" asp-for="phoneNumber" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 }
```

And I have the following code in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiveForm1(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IEnumerable<Form1Return> personData = GetPersonInformation(collection);
        return View(personData);
    }
```

When I run the code, and enter data into the form, and click the submit button, I run to a breakpoint set on call to GetPersonInformation.  When I do a watch on collection, there are no elements.  So for some reason, the form data is not making it to the controller.  Any idea why?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: try add [FromForm]   public ActionResult ReceiveForm1([FromForm] FormCollection collection)

Comment: sorry, I forgot to enter [HttpPost] above the method.  See the edited version.  I tried adding [FromForm] but that gave an error and offered to install a package for .NET CORE.  Im not in .NET CORE.

Comment: What is the status code in response?

Comment: @jdweng I dont see any status code.  I pasted an image of the values I see in collection from the watch windwon

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Have you checked that the rendered `input` tags have a `name` attribute set on them?

Comment: @lee-m YES!  I had asp-for but not name.  Now, I have id, asp-for, and name, just to be on the safe side.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I'll add this as an answer so it's more visible to anyone else coming across this.

Comment: Set the `name` attribute to all `input` tags and on the Controller side use `Request.Form["Name"]` to retrieve the value of form elements.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when `input`'s don't have their `name` attribute set. The relevant section on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) has this nugget which confirms this is likely the case.

> Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinder' cannot bind to a model of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection'. Change the model type to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection' instead.

Please try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiveForm1(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        IEnumerable<Form1Return> personData = GetPersonInformation(collection);
        return View(personData);
    }
```